# Passing bash variables to rollup.js

Tags: bash, rollupjs

I am trying to pass a variable to rollup.js in bash.
I don’t know if this is a bash problem, or a problem with rollup.js, because I am not that experienced in bash. But maybe someone can help me out here …

Here is my terminal input:

```
MY_INPUT="/path to my/input.js"
MY_OUTPUT="/path to my/output.js"
rollup --input $MY_INPUT --output $MY_OUTPUT
```

Rollup throws the error:

> rollup can only bundle one file at a time

**I tracked down the problem to the whitespace inside the path.**

However, both of these work:

```
rollup --input "/path to my/input.js" --output "/path to my/output.js"
rollup --input /path\ to\ my/input.js --output /path\ to\ my/output.js
```

The problem only occurs, when I use variables.
I also tried to escape the variables instead of putting it in parenthesis, but that did not work either.

Is there any way to get the variables to behave like I want them to, is that a problem, that rollup.js has to deal with, or is it simply not possible to use paths with whitespace in it as arguments through variables?

Comment: you can enable the bash set +x option to enable bash logging to see what is happening to debug this more..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the variables as you pass them to `rollup`:

```
rollup --input "$MY_INPUT" --ouput "$MY_OUTPUT"
```

It's because these variables contain spaces, which the shell interprets as multiple arguments. By quoting using double quotes, the values will be interpreted as a single string.

Note that if you copy-paste your Bash scripts on http://www.shellcheck.net/#, it can point out issues like this.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried that. But tried it again and it works! I will accept it, as soon as the time limit is up. :)

Comment: And a special thanks for pointing out the link to shellcheck, didn’t know about that one.